# how to retrieve label from a HTML class in a table using Swift

Tags: swift, shtml, swiftsoup

Trying to retrieve: "17,02" from the HTML below:

```
<div class="overflow-auto">
    <table class="w-100 tl mb4 mt3 f6" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="fw6 bb b--black-20 tl pb3 pr3 bg-white tl">Kvalitet</th>
                <th class="fw6 bb b--black-20 tl pb3 pr3 bg-white tl">Pris inkl. mva.</th>
                <th class="fw6 bb b--black-20 tl pb3 pr3 bg-white tl">Endring</th>
                <th class="fw6 bb b--black-20 tl pb3 pr3 bg-white tl">Gjeldene fra</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="lh-copy">
            <tr>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20"><img src="./assets/95 Miles.png" alt="95 Miles"></td>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">Kr 17,02</td>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">5 øre</td>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">24.08.2018</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="lh-copy">
            <tr>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20"><img src="./assets/D Miles.png" alt="D Miles"></td>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">Kr 15,80</td>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">5 øre</td>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">24.08.2018</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="lh-copy">
            <tr>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20"><img src="./assets/95 Miles Plus.png" alt="95 Miles"></td>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">Kr 18,01</td>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">5 øre</td>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">24.08.2018</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="lh-copy">
            <tr>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20"><img src="./assets/D Miles Plus.png" alt="D Miles"></td>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">Kr 16,79</td>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">5 øre</td>
                <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">24.08.2018</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I've tried using this code in swift:

```
let titles = try doc.getElementsByClass("pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20").array()
```

But when I try to print it out I get nil back. Does anyone have any solutions or ideas?

Comment: Try `. select("td.pv3.pr3.bb.b--black-20")`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Tried it, but still nothing

Comment: You want "Kr 17,02" or just "17,02"?

Answer (score 1):

To select an element that belongs to at least one of many classes, separate these classes with a comma:

```
let tds: [Element] = try doc.select(".pv3, .pr3, .bb, .b--black-20")
```

Use this to select the second `td`:

```
let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
let td: Element = try doc.select("tbody tr td").array()[1]
let text: String = try td.text()
```

The selector "tbody tr td" looks for all `td`s inside a `tr` inside of a `tbody`. And then we know that the second `td` is the one we want. So, we convert the result to an array, and then the we select the second element in that array by using the subscript `[1]`.

If you're sure you want just the second td in your html document, then the selector could be shortened :

```
let td: Element = try doc.select("td").array()[1]
```

If you want to get all the second `td`s in your table which text starts with "Kr " :

```
let tds: [Element] = try doc.select("tr td").array().filter { try $0.text().starts(with: "Kr ")}
let labels: [String] = try tds.map {try $0.text()}
```

If you want the text of these `td`s but without "Kr " :

```
let tds: [Element] = try doc.select("td").array().filter { try $0.text().starts(with: "Kr ")}
let titlesWithoutKr: [String] = try tds.map {try String($0.text().dropFirst(3))}
```

Here is the final code:

```
do {
    let html: String =  """
                        <div class="overflow-auto">
                            <table class="w-100 tl mb4 mt3 f6" cellspacing="0">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="fw6 bb b--black-20 tl pb3 pr3 bg-white tl">Kvalitet</th>
                                        <th class="fw6 bb b--black-20 tl pb3 pr3 bg-white tl">Pris inkl. mva.</th>
                                        <th class="fw6 bb b--black-20 tl pb3 pr3 bg-white tl">Endring</th>
                                        <th class="fw6 bb b--black-20 tl pb3 pr3 bg-white tl">Gjeldene fra</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="lh-copy">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20"><img src="./assets/95 Miles.png" alt="95 Miles"></td>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">Kr 17,02</td>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">5 øre</td>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">24.08.2018</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <tbody class="lh-copy">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20"><img src="./assets/D Miles.png" alt="D Miles"></td>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">Kr 15,80</td>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">5 øre</td>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">24.08.2018</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <tbody class="lh-copy">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20"><img src="./assets/95 Miles Plus.png" alt="95 Miles"></td>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">Kr 18,01</td>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">5 øre</td>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">24.08.2018</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <tbody class="lh-copy">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20"><img src="./assets/D Miles Plus.png" alt="D Miles"></td>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">Kr 16,79</td>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">5 øre</td>
                                        <td class="pv3 pr3 bb b--black-20">24.08.2018</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        """
    let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
    let tds: [Element] = try doc.select("td").array().filter { try $0.text().starts(with: "Kr ")}
    let titlesWithoutKr: [String] = try tds.map {try String($0.text().dropFirst(3))}
    print(titlesWithoutKr)
} catch Exception.Error( _, let message) {
    print(message)
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

And it prints `["17,02", "15,80", "18,01", "16,79"]`.

For more documentation on how to use SwiftSoup, have a look [here](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup).

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with this, but they all come back as empty arrays: "[]" when I try to print them out.

Comment: @Shift I get `["17,02", "15,80", "18,01", "16,79"]` with the last one